# Angular 4 Skip Links

Tags: javascript, angular, focus, accessibility

Working on making an angular project accessible.  Page has a frame like this: where each element is a component.

```
<div>
<topnav> </topnav>
<leftnav> </leftnav>
<subnav> </subnav>
<header> </header>
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</div>
```

I would put the skip link in the top nav, and having the event emitted to the frame is easy, but how would I direct it to focus the first focusable element in the router-outlet by default?  I know I could use view child and grab a reference to the outlet and then access the child nodes through that, but it's not always going to be the same node index.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to focus on router-outlet component on page load, if yes try putting focus on router-outlet's component's OnInit!

Comment: I don't want to focus on the router outlet on load.  The initial focus should be the first element in the top nav.  A skip link would be used to jump over the navigation and straight to the content within the router outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually skip-to-content links go to a container element, not the first focusable element. Because there might be text content before the first link/input/etc that screenreader users will want to know about.

Give the router-outlet container an `id` attribute and make the `href` value of your link the same value. e.g.

```
<a href="#output">
<div id="output">
```